# WPF - binding two properties on the different dialogs

Tags: c#, wpf

I have two options on different dialogs (classes) related to CheckBox in different XAML files:

**First pair:**

*C#:*

```
public class FirstClass : DependencyObject
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty testProperty = 
      DependencyProperty.Register("testProperty", typeof(bool),
      typeof(FirstClass), 
      new UIPropertyMetadata(false));

   public bool testProperty
   {
      get { return (bool)this.GetValue(testProperty); }
      set { this.SetValue(testProperty, value); }
   }
}
```

*XAML:*

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=testProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

**Second pair:**

*C#*

```
public class SecondClass : DependencyObject
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty testProperty =
      FirstClass.testProperty.AddOwner(typeof(SecondClass));

   public bool testProperty
   {
      get { return (bool)this.GetValue(testProperty); }
      set { this.SetValue(testProperty, value); }
   }
}
```

*XAML:*

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=testProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

I want to bind the option from the first dialog to the option from the second dialog (A<=>B). If the CheckBox in the first dialog is checked, the CheckBox in the second dialog should also be checked. Should I use *ApplicationSettings* for this purpose?

Comment: Why not store the data in a data object (usually called model) and just using it again in the second dialog?

Comment: Because I do not know this solution. Could you provide a link to some example?

Comment: Could you explain us more of what you are trying to do? It is easy to fix your problem but it might be much easier to do it another way (if it is possible.)

Comment: I have the dialog with the settings, which is divided into the tabs.  Each tab is represented by a separate class. In the two tabs is an option that represents the same setting. I want to get effect that if I click the CheckBox on the first tab, the same option on the second tab is also checked. I want to connect these two options at the settings dialog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataBinding is not only the process of binding between two dependency properties, but also between one CLR and one dependency property. In fact it usually is the most common binding scenario. So what you can do is use a model object which stores the value of your ui elements and reuse it in another view or another control. 
First of all i advise you not to use a DependencyObject derived object as your data holder, while its still valid it has it cons aswell.

First our data object, which stores just our data. Please lookup how to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, because i left the implementation for readability.

```
class DataHolder : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool MyValue
    {
        get{return mMyValue;}
        set{mMyValue = value; RaiseProperty("MyValue");}
    }

    private bool mMyValue;
}
```

This object can now be easily bound to your ui elements with the help of the UI DataContext. Its vital to know that the DataContext is an inherited dependency property, which means that in the tree of controls, if an element doesn't have a set datacontext it automatically gets the datacontext of his parent. Think of a login dialog with user name and password. If you have a simple model with two properties like user name and password, you just set this model as the datacontext to the dialog and all controls can bind to these properties. Back to your example, you just set an instance of DataHolder to your window datacontext property

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponents();
    var model = new DataHolder();
    DataContext = model;
}
```

and now you can use bindings in your xaml like this

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding MyValue, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Multiple controls can bind to the same property, and you can use the same model when you open another view.

One last advice, you should read the [DataBinding chapter of the msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) and its a good idea to look into the [MVVM pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) because its widely used with WPF to great success. We use it for a rather large application and are very satisfied with it.